# Load CSS classes (with transitions) from cookies without transitioning into them

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, css-transitions

Here goes my first post on stackoverflow!

I have created css to transition between two different background colors.

```
.body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
        transition: background 5s;
        webkit-transition: background 5s;
}
.bodyclick {
    background-color:#333

}
```

It's for a photo gallery type page and I like having different background options to view the images on. I have also used javascript/jQuery to both transition between the two colors when an object with the class "project name" is clicked and store the current background state in a cookie so that the background color will remain constant as you navigate through different pages.

```
// toggles 'bodyclick' class on the body based on the click of an object with the class projectname and sets the state in a cookie

$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $('.projectname');

    //check the cookie when the page loads
    if ($.cookie('currentToggle') === 'hidden') {
        toggleBackground(button, false);
    }
    else {
        toggleBackground(button, true);
    }

    //handle the clicking of the background (projectname)  toggle button
    button.click(function() {
        //toggle the background as required, base on current state
        if ($('.body').hasClass('bodyclick')) {
            toggleBackground($(this), true);
        }
        else {
            toggleBackground($(this), false);
        }
    });

});

function toggleBackground(button, show) {

    var background = $('.body');

    if (show) {
        background.removeClass('bodyclick');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', '', { path: '/' });
    }
    else {
        background.addClass('bodyclick');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', 'hidden', { path: '/' });
    }
};
```

The only problem I have now is that when the cookie is set to the dark grey color and you refresh or navigate to a separate page it transitions from the default color (white) to the dark grey when the page loads instead of just staying constant. It loads immediately to the color that I want if I remove the transition property from the CSS but I like transition effect when clicking to change the background.

If you want to view it live you can visit this [page](http://constellates.com/post_consumer.php)

and click on the text on the bottom right that says "post consumer" to change the color and then refresh or navigate to a different page.

Let me know how I might make this transition only when clicking and not on page load or if I need to better clarify my question.

Also as a side question. Can anyone explain what the 'hidden' and 'show' values are doing in my javascript? I'm new to programming and I borrowed code from a stackoverflow post and modified it do what I needed but I don't fully understand how those values are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and remove a second class which overrides the transitions of the first:

```
.no-transition {
    transition: all 0s !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s !important;
}
```

JS:

```
background.addClass('no-transition').addClass('bodyclick').removeClass('no-transition');
```

Comment: Thanks, This solution worked with a bit of tweaking. I used the .no-transition class and used javascript to add in when the document loaded then removed it on.click of the transition button.